# Time Machine does not recognize my MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, backup, time-machine

Due to a clicking and beeping problem on my Macbook Pro (MBP), I got a 1 to 1 replacement from Apple which arrived today. I was able to my original setting using Time Machine restore. That works great.

But after the restore and software update, the click on Time Machine to back up. But it says it doesn't recognize the backups. Now I am doing a full backup again that will take me a better of an hour.

So what's the problem? How come Time Machine does not recognise the backups it restore from?

Comment: for those interested in the clicking and beeping problem of the Mid 2009 MBP with 7200rpm HDD read here---> http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2049659&start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each backup disk is associated with your MacBook through both your computer name and the [MAC Address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of the first network port. When you get a new logic board then that MAC Address will have changed, even if you use the very same internal hard disk (and hence the same computer name).

If you would still have used the same internal hard disk, then you could have followed the instructions on [10.5: Repair Time Machine after logic board changes](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080128003716101) and [10.5: A script to fix Time Machine after hardware repairs](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20081216145458979) from macosxhints.com (be sure to browse through the comments on that site as well).

However, as you restored some settings, it seems you also have a new internal disk. In that case, I think it is not a good idea to try to associate your old backup with the new hardware. See [How do you re-associate an Airport Time Machine backup after migrating to a new mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/165/how-do-you-re-associate-an-airport-time-machine-backup-after-migrating-to-a-new-m/876#876)

Note that holding down Option while clicking the Time Machine icon will make "Enter Time Machine" change into "Browse Other Time Machine Disks", wich allows you to restore from *any* backup.

Answer (score 0):

Do your replacement and original computers have the same computer name? It's in the Sharing pane in System Preferences.

Comment: How do I know my computor name? Is it my log in name?